# pipe tail output into another script

Tags: bash, parameters, pipe, tail

I am trying to pipe the output of a tail command into another bash script to process:

```
tail -n +1 -f your_log_file | myscript.sh
```

However, when I run it, the $1 parameter (inside the myscript.sh) never gets reached.  What am I missing?  How do I pipe the output to be the input parameter of the script?

PS - I want tail to run forever and continue piping each individual line into the script.

**Edit**
For now the entire contents of myscripts.sh are:

```
echo $1;
```

Comment: You're missing an argument to assign to `$1`. The pipe connects the output of tail to the standard input of your script. Can you post `myscript.sh`, or at least enough to determine whether you need an argument (and what that argument should be), and how it will handle the data presented on its standard input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally, here is one way to handle standard input to a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    echo $line
done
```

That is a very rough bash equivalent to `cat`. It does demonstrate a key fact: each command inside the script inherits its standard input from the shell, so you don't really need to do anything special to get access to the data coming in. `read` takes its input from the shell, which (in your case) is getting its input from the `tail` process connected to it via the pipe.

As another example, consider this script; we'll call it 'mygrep.sh'.

```
#!/bin/bash

grep "$1"
```

Now the pipeline

```
some-text-producing-command | ./mygrep.sh bob
```

behaves identically to

```
some-text-producing-command | grep bob
```

---

`$1` is set if you call your script like this:

```
./myscript.sh foo
```

Then `$1` has the value "foo".

The positional parameters and standard input are separate; you could do this

```
tail -n +1 -f your_log_file | myscript.sh foo
```

Now standard input is still coming from the `tail` process, and `$1` is still set to 'foo'.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Where is foo coming from / getting populated?

Comment: 'foo' is just an arbitrary string on the command line. If there is a string that follows your command, that is what gets assigned to `$1`. If there is a second string, that gets assigned to `$2`, and so forth. In your original example, you had no arguments following `myscript.sh`, which is why `$1` had no value.

Comment: right - so how do I pipe the output of tail into myscript.sh?  do I just incorporate it into myscript.sh?  If so, how?

Comment: Any command in your script that reads from standard input will read from the pipe. Run the sample script at the top of my answer in a pipeline to see how it works.

Comment: Sorry for being dense.  Worked perfectly when I plugged it in correctly!

Comment: @chepner, for a `cat` equivalent, the loop should have `echo "$line"`, not `echo -n "$line"`.

Comment: This doesn't work with `ls | awk '\pattern\' {getline; print $2}' | ./myscript.sh`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your were confused with `awk`?

```
tail -n +1 -f your_log_file | awk '{
    print $1
}'
```

would print the first column from the output of the tail command.

In the shell, a similar effect can be achieved with:

```
tail -n +1 -f your_log_file | while read first junk; do
    echo "$first"
done
```

Alternatively, you could put the whole `while ... done` loop inside `myscript.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Piping connects the output (`stdout`) of one process to the input (`stdin`) of another process. `stdin` is not the same thing as the arguments sent to a process when it starts.

What you want to do is convert the lines in the output of your first process into arguments for the the second process. This is exactly what the [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) command is for.

**All you need to do is pipe an `xargs` in between the initial command and it will work**:

`tail -n +1 -f your_log_file | xargs | myscript.sh`